# Get client IP at target wcf service after routing

Tags: wcf, service, routes, router

I got a problem after implemented WCF routing.
The situation is  a have 2 server A and B,  At server A is installed a WCF serice ( target service) it needs to get IP of clients for check session. Server B is placed WCF router  and all clients will only request to server B ( do not directly to real server A) .

Now, problem is server A only get IP of the server B, instead of real IP for each client. I would like to know these are any solutions for get  real client's IP after routing like above ?

Answer (score 1):

So you put your Code which use to get IP in server A into Server B. Server A now just need to catch IP sent back from Sever B

Comment: that's no good,  by the way, i must deploy another wcf service on server B instead of wcf router.